# Why User is registering instead showing err 11000 in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Repo : https://github.com/heet-vakharia/codepen-cloned-server
I m creating Codepen Clone Backend using mongoose
I dont why but register route is not working
It is showing is this err on creating new user

```
{
    "err": {
        "driver": true,
        "name": "MongoError",
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "keyPattern": {
            "pens.id": 1
        },
        "keyValue": {
            "pens.id": null
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Reagister Route function

```
const register = async (req, res, User, bcrypt) => {
  const { userid, password } = req.body;

  if (userid && password) {
    var encryptedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 8);
    User.create(
      {
        userid: userid,
        password: encryptedPassword,
        pens: [],
      },
      (err, user) => {
           if (err) {
            res.status(405).status(err);
          } else {
             res.status(201).json(user);
         }
      }
    );
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: "Plz provide all information" });
  }
};
export default register;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code 11000 means you're trying to save a duplicate record. From the repo, `userid` is unique so when you try to save the same record twice you'll get code 11000.

You should instead look to use an update function (even when creating new records). When you use {upsert:true}, new documents will be inserted into the collection, while existing records will be updated.

`findOneAndUpdate()` is a [useful function](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).